# MAVEN / Eclipse TargetPlatform

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-plugin, nexus

We are building an Eclipse RCP plugin that is based on an Eclipse target platform (also developed internally in our company, by a different department). We would like to compile the plugin using MAVEN2 (we also use NEXUS for repository management).

The target platform consists of about 130 JARs (most of them org.eclipse.*). One way to perform the build would be to add 130 references into the  tag of the POM file. Not only is this a lot of effort, but the target platform occasionally changes, so a new target platform would mean a lot of modifications.

Is there a better way to deal with a lot of dependencies in MAVEN?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [All Client jBoss](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/jbossas/jboss-as-client/5.0.0.GA/jboss-as-client-5.0.0.GA.pom) artifact. They have solved the same problem using POM artifact.